# How to know which revision or router I do have?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I´m trying to update my **D-link Dir-600** router with the dd-wrt firmware.

I´ve searched for it at [the site](http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) and found that:

Revision A1, B1 and B2 are supported, while C isn´t.

Now my router has this information on the back:

```
P/N IIR600GNA .... C1G 
H/W Ver: C1 F/W Ver: 3.01
```

So I guess the H/W Ver is the revision, and it´s C... so it´s a lost cause? Or maybe because it´s not just C but C1 I could do something with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On D-Link Routers the H/W-Version shows the revision, so for yours it's C1.

If the router database doesn't name your exact model I don't recommend to update because the device will probably get bricked. Maybe you find some more information in the [forum](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/) or in the [wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).